# VBA checkboxes: an elegant solution required

Tags: vba

I have a VBA problem that we are looking for a quick and elegant solution.

The issue regards check-boxes: their selection and de-selection.

Say we start with a row and four columns of data (cells A1:A4:

```
A   B   Star    D
```

we have three *unchecked* boxes:  `Galaxy`,  `Universe`, `Planet`.

upon checking `Galaxy`, the row is dynamically copied (to the next empty row) as such

```
A   B   Star    D
A   B   Galaxy  D
```

if we check all three we have:

```
A   B   Star    D
A   B   Galaxy  D
A   B   UniverseD
A   B   Planet  D
```

Now, if we un-check `Universe`..  that row is automatically omitted to:

```
A   B   Star    D
A   B   Galaxy  D
A   B   Planet  D
```

I like the real-time 'as you see it' feel of such a set up.  Is there an elegant approach I cant take to coding this?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your 'not so elegant' solution for this?

Comment: Dont' forget to accept some of the fine answers you've received on your previous questions.

Comment: Where are the checkboxes located?

Comment: What type the checkboxes are? Forms 2.0 OR Activex?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetDataBasedOnSelection(ByVal galaxyChecked As Boolean, ByVal universeChecked As Boolean, _
ByVal planetChecked As Boolean) As Variant
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim retVal(1 To 3, 1 To 4)

currentRow = 1
If galaxyChecked Then
    GoSub fillInCommonValuesInThisRow
    retVal(currentRow, 3) = "Galaxy"
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
End If

If universeChecked Then
    GoSub fillInCommonValuesInThisRow
    retVal(currentRow, 3) = "Universe"
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
End If

If planetChecked Then
    GoSub fillInCommonValuesInThisRow
    retVal(currentRow, 3) = "Planet"
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
End If

GetDataBasedOnSelection = retVal
Exit Function

fillInCommonValuesInThisRow:
    retVal(currentRow, 1) = "A"
    retVal(currentRow, 2) = "B"
    retVal(currentRow, 3) = ""
    retVal(currentRow, 4) = "D"
Return
End Function
```

How to use the above method:

```
'Pass the actual selection (true if the checkbox is checked, false otherwise)
Range("A2:D4").Value = GetDataBasedOnSelection(True, False, True)
```

Comment: @user1717622: Please include all your comments in 1 box & delete rest of it. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Shahkalpesh, I am modifying this now for my sheet, the actual version contains a few differences, but I like your thinking here.. I'll give you feedback shortly on my attempt! checkboxes are Form 2.0 btw

Comment: @user1717622: If you find this answer helpful, please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: having a few issues with this. Firstly, only one of the checkboxes is actually working at a time and this fails to output the universe row, but outputs 2 rows. Then when i de-check the box, the rows to do not disappear. If you provide email I can send you how how I have assigned the the macro's to each checkbox.. which may be wrong.

Comment: Please share the file using dropbox or ge.tt and share the link of the excel file with me.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69651453/test1.xlsx       If you wish I can send you the actual full tool we are building..   one of the key functions is that multiple rows are copied down with every check, this may be clear on the full example.